# Slow loading/recovery of client after game ends

Tags: league-of-legends

Since a certain patch - I cannot determine which one, like 6 months ago - I began experiencing an issue where my client is stuck on a *"Game in progress..."* screen for a minute after I finish a game. I tried:

- reinstalling LoL
- reinstalling LoL to a brand new SSD
- moving my TEMP/TMP directories to said SSD
- killing the LeagueOfLegends.exe process after game

  - this seemed to have an effect as opposed to the other tries: The client returns to the post-game screen immediately, but is extremely slow - graphs load slowly, returning to the party screen (Play again) works, but my friends do not see me as connected, after the minute passes (during which no actions are viable) a lot of screens blink and then the party screen opens again and everything works
- letting the client close during a game

  - this just causes it to open immediately and then proceed with *"Game in progress..."* as before.

Comment: Does this help? This person had the same problem where they couldn't get out of a game and fixed it by changing their region.
https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1eq3lo/stuck_in_ghost_game_for_2_days_game_still_in/

Comment: @snoozingnewt That sounds like a different problem than mine, but I have nothing to lose, I'll check it out. That dude was stuck in a single game for eternity (read for days), my issue is that my after game client just returns to normal behavior way later than it shoud (read for minutes).

Comment: Sorry, I misread how long it took for it to load - From my personal experience I had similar lag in LoL and other games before, and I realized it was because I was using a VPN, if you're using one (and you started 6 months ago) try turning it off

Comment: @snoozingnewt Interesting. However, during that time, I have not introduced any drastic changes to my internet connection. Also, I wonder what could that issue have in common with the IC in general - if i kill the game process, the client enters the correct page immediately - it just fails to react to my input (becomes extremely laggy) for a minute, until something (in the background) loads and then suddenly everything works okay.

Answer (score 1):

It is a running joke that Riot's client is a mess. Its spaghetti code. And it comes with a bunch of quirks and crashes.

Really, I've seen toasters not have any problems with the client, and super powered PCs struggle with it. I would guess the client simply has problem with some combination of parts, or things like firewalls and stuff.

The only thing I do think might help is look at your logs; LoL has a tendency to drop error in a log, never clean it and it can become huge. That could cause your problem if it has to open the file and write at the end of every game. Basically look into `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Logs` and you can delete whatever is in there. I do think it stays even if you uninstall/reinstall. https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/8uhk04/psa_delete_your_game_logs_every_once_in_a_while/

If that doesn't change anything, sadly, I do not think there is an answer except try to buy a new computer and try your luck.

Comment: Holy shit, I didn't realize Riot might not be using rolling logs. I'm checking that out immediately.

Comment: Nah, they are definitely rolling. Only the most recent days remain, and I wager the overall size stays constant. I'll try purging all of them, but they are inside the `Riot Games` folder, whose removal is part of the reinstallation process tried I've mentioned, so no hopes. Honestly, Riot's games are one of the cleanest written (bug-free in comparison) games I've ever played, but god damn, the client is a massive, undisguised turd dropped right on our heads. Sadge

Comment: Yeah I went and checked, because I thought it was creating/updating one file of error_log. But no its making basically a new file every game. So my theory is not holding much water. But my original point still stands. The Riot Client has a history of being just weird and struggling on computer builds that should run it perfectly fine or even run laps around whatever is needed to run it.

Comment: Yeah, good to know that my PC does not need replacement or something. Just the game needs replacing

Comment: Yeah I really wonder how far we are from Riot just doing a reset on the client and starting from scratch.

Comment: Very close, I hope :D

Answer (score 0):

Today, I found out that a possible fix is to leave the game before the nexus blows up. The client suddenly loads perfectly without any issues. This confirms my suspicion that this issue is not related to my hardware, but to the blunk that is LoL client code.